# it is impossible to create a custom ListView in ListFragment

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I imported the library [1]: https://github.com/shontauro/android-pulltorefresh-and-loadmore

Example class was extending `ListActivity` and all works.
  I redid on `extends ListFragment` and there was an error.

```
 public class SurveyGuestsList extends ListFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.loadmore, null);

        arrayList = new ArrayList<SurveyGuestsListBean>();
        context = getActivity();
        new LoadDataTask().execute();

//        set a listener to be invoked when the list reaches the end
        ((LoadMoreListView) getListView())
                .setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
                    public void onLoadMore() {
                        // Do the work to load more items at the end of list
                        // here
                        new LoadDataTask().execute();
                    }
                });
        return v;
    }
```

ERROR:

```
11-18 07:34:10.508    1777-1777/com.example.MANAGMENT E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created
            at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:328)
            at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.getListView(ListFragment.java:222)
            at com.example.MANAGMENT.fragments.SurveyGuestsList.onCreateView(SurveyGuestsList.java:50)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:454)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDITE:
I moved the code here and it worked !!!

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ((LoadMoreListView) getListView())
                .setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
                    public void onLoadMore() {
                        // Do the work to load more items at the end of list here
                        new LoadDataTask().execute();
                    }
                });
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Comment: post code for ListActivity

Comment: https://github.com/shontauro/android-pulltorefresh-and-loadmore
below example. I do unchanging in code except the parent class

Comment: ListFragment is not ListActivity, I assume you know diff between Activity and Fragments. For Activity to work you call setContentView() to give Activity a View. I think you are not setting it

Comment: I did not understand you. I have now ListFragment. 
I need exactly it. What am I doing wrong in the code? and yes, my loadmorexml says "Rendering problems"

Comment: @Murtaza Hussain I also can not understand your comment. The issue is getListView() is called too early, that's all it seems to be.

Comment: @Alex yeah, you are right, view is not created. I was assuming something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fragments and Activities have different life-cycles and call backs.  For fragments, onCreateView is for creating the view it is not attached to the view hierarchy until you return `v`, so you cannot call `getListView` in it.  Just create and return your view as follows.

```
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.loadmore, null);
    return v;
  }
```

Move the rest of your code to [`onViewCreated()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onViewCreated%28android.view.View,%20android.os.Bundle%29) or a later callback.

Answer (score 1):

In your `onCreateView` you are using `getListView()`. See, `getListView()` returns the view which `onCreateView` creates.  So, you are trying to use it before `onCreateView()` returns. Therefore the error `'Content view is not yet created'.`

Try using `v` instead of `getListView()` in your `onCreateView()`

```
((LoadMoreListView)v).setonLoadMoreListener(...);
```